# Facebook Graph API - How to search friends by relationship_status?

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the Facebook AS3 API and I'm having trouble sorting friends by relationship_status. I'm using the following call:

```
Facebook.API("/" + UID + "/friends?relationship_status='single'&access_token=" + ACCESS_TOKEN);
```

I have the following permissions enabled:

```
"publish_stream","read_friendlists", "user_photo_video_tags", "user_relationships", "user_checkins", "user_interests", "user_photos", "friends_relationships", "friends_relationship_details"
```

Is there something I'm missing permissions-wise?

I've tried this on the Graph API Explorer and it just doesn't work. From my Flash application I get the following error:

**OAuthException : Error validating application.**

I'm not having any other authentication problems with other calls thus far.

I appreciate any help or insight you can provide. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up doing this via a batch request. Code below:

```
var batchObj:Array = [

{ 
    method:"GET", 
    name: "get-friends", 
    relative_url: "me/friends" 
},
{ 
    method:"GET", 
    relative_url: "?ids={result=get-friends:$.data.*.id}"
}
];

var batchRequest:String = JSON.stringify(batchObj);             
var params:Object = {               
    access_token: _accessToken,
    batch: batchRequest
}

Facebook.api("/", onRequestComplete, params, "POST");
```